# How come BorderPane does not display any content

Tags: javafx, gluon, borderpane

I created a mobile application and now I am going forth to make the code easier and more precise. I want to switch one of the pages from a lot of cluster to a borderpane since it will make my code cleaner. For some reason when I comment the working code to use a borderpane my labels and everything else does not display. I feel as if it is something small I do not see

I have tried making a scene, setLeft action

```
public BookNow(){

BorderPane bookClub = new BorderPane();
Vbox labels = new VBox();
Label city = new Labels("City: ");
Label venue= new Labels("Venue: ");   
Label date = new Labels("Date: ");   
Label appArrivalTime = new Labels("Approxiamte Time of Arrival: ");

labels.getChildren().addAll(city, venue, date, appArrivalTime);
bookClub.setLeft(labels);

}
```

It should just show the labels on the left side of the BorderPane.

Comment: If this is all the code relating to the `BorderPane`, you never add it to a scene or a parent part of a scene. Otherwise, there's not enough information to diagnose the problem; please provide a [mre] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Does BorderPane only work within a scene?

Comment: If so how do you use that with the Gluon mobile plugin

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gluon Mobile. If there's some abstraction that hides away the use of a `Scene`, use that instead. Whatever the case, you need to add the `BorderPane` to _something_; all your code snippet does is create it and then throw it away. Gluon appears to provide [various documentation](https://gluonhq.com/developers/documentation/) for their products—something there may prove helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Where do you insert the `BorderPane` element? You have to insert your component into the `Scene` instance that is called into the main FXML `Stage` and then initialize your `BorderPane` with all the elements. In addition, writing code info the FXML file is way clearer than into Java class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <left>
        <VBox>
            <Label>City: </Label>
            <Label>Venue: </Label>
            <Label>Date: </Label>
            <Label>Approximate Time of Arrival: </Label>
        </VBox>
    </left>
</BorderPane>
```

You have to link your FXML file (for example, 'view.fxml') to the JavaFX application window using `FXMLLoader.load()`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/package/path/to/the/fxml/file/view.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Do it answer your question?

Comment: Do you have an answer for Mike, kleopatra?

Comment: take part in SO for a couple of years - and you'll learn why the rules are like they are and why it is important to teach newbies to follow them ;)

Comment: I have not used fxml before so I am unfamiliar

Comment: Do I need a scene in order for BorderPane to work? I am using the Gluon plugin for mobile applications

Comment: Yes, you need to declare it in Java, I've updated the answer.